# shrink the parent window instead of having other widgets grow

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout, qt4

I have a window, which only contains one groupbox, which contains several more groupboxes in a QVBoxLayout (the content of those doesnt have a fixed size either). Those inner groupboxes are checkable, and unchecking them collapses them (collapsed groupbox has a reduced (maximum)height of 30px and isFlat==true).

What i am trying to achieve is:
When one of the inner groupboxes is collapsed, the outer groupbox and the window should shrink accordingly (currently the other non-collapsed groupboxes grow instead). But the user should still be able to resize the window, which should cause the groupboxes to grow accordingly:

[image]
I was toying around with `QWidget::setSizePolicy` and `QLayout::setSizeConstraint` of the different layouts/widgets, but havent come to a satisfying result yet..
Whats the best way to achieve this ? Can this be done without implementing your own size-hint functions ?

Comment: I'm no usability expert but this sound like a bad idea. Personally, I don't like windows that resize automatically.

Comment: @Job: They would only do that if you uncheck one of the inner groupboxes. I have the choice between automatically resizing groupboxes and the automatically resizing window... and resizing of the inner groupboxes is ugly in my case, so i would like to avoid that if the user only unchecks one of the other groupboxes... if the user resizes the window on his own, i cant avoid that, but thats kinda fine, because its obvious that resizing the window means that the contents have to be rearranged..

Answer (score 2):

I made a toy case that seems to have the behaviour you require by calling

```
adjustSize();
```

on the parent QGroupBox after resizing the inner QGroupBoxes.  I made this a slot so I could connect it to the same signal that resizes the inner group box for convenience.

Comment: hmmm if i call `adjustSize()` the outer QGroupBox does no longer stretch itself to fit the window, nor does the window shrink to fit the groupbox.

Comment: I guess your size settings right now overwrite the behavior I was seeing, can you share more code?

Comment: Since its a closed source project i cant release the code sorry, but i can tell you that the collapsing functionality of the groupbox classes we are using (for the innner groupboxes) should work quite similar to http://jpnurmi.kapsi.fi/docs/classQxtGroupBox.html (so try using this as inner groupbox). Also make sure you have content in the inner groupboxes which can be expanded (`(widget.sizePolicy() | QSizePolicy::GrowFlag) == true`)